# geojson correct file path

Tags: python, geojson, folium, choropleth

if the geojson file is as follows:
How would I plot the correct file path?

```
{
"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{

"type": "Feature", "geometry": {

"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[-74.05149192582515, 40.711751797471194], [-74.04668044585559, 40.72067578257309],
```

```
# Choropleth creates a 'Heat map' as an overlay 
listings_map.choropleth(
geo_data = 'jersey-city-ward-and-councilperson-map-2018.geojson',
data = listings, # airBnb listings dataset.
columns = ['latitude', 'longitude'],
key_on = 'features.geometry.coordinates') #(this seems to be incorrect)
#fill_color = 'PuRd', fill_opacity = 0.5, line_opacity = 0.2,
#legend_name = 'neighbourhood').add_to(listings_map)
```

I am clearly not stating the issue correctly. I am trying to use a geojson file to create a choropleth map using folium. It works until I attempt to use the key_on feature. which causes an error. of which I am assuming there is either an issue with the geojson file or am I am using key_on incorrectly.

when I run the code I get an trackback error ending in:

"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'"

Comment: Also: This is a clip of the geojson file:
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[-74.05149192582515, 40.711751797471194],

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
We expect a minimal working example of the problem, including appropriate code to trace the internal operation.

Comment: We also expect that you will trace the suspect values just before the point of error. Where are you confused about how they got to those values?

Comment: Nothing in your code references "Key_on" or "color_fill".  You need to show us the code that isn't working.  Don't do it in a comment, edit your question.  And there are no files here at all, so talking about a "file path" is not meaningful.

Comment: @TimRoberts  apologies, I had it up but was down voted so I attempted to get to heart of the issue.

Comment: One reason for the error is that the reference to the referenced GEOJSON file is a string. The second is the code that key_on is set to, which is. `key_on = 'feature.geometry.coordinates'`

Comment: It's feature, not features. And the last part) is unnecessary.

Comment: @r-beginners should the geojson reference not be a string? Im pretty new to this so that is a real question. Also when I change features to feature i get a new error:

"  TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'   "

Comment: Here is a [sample page](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/GeoJSON_and_choropleth.ipynb) for your reference.

Comment: The basic structure is to visualize the data of the data frame on the map of folium using the polygon information of GEOJSON, and to associate the key information in the data row of the polygon information with the column name of the data frame in GEOJSON. This is the key point.

Comment: @r-beginners thank you :) I'm at work at the moment but going to go over the link afterwards. Thank you for answering, linking and your help. I'll update once I get it going.